# Do we need to keep application running until glacier upload complete?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

My application uploads the file to Amazon glacier using AWS SDK .NET APIs.
My question is do i need to keep my application  running (4-6 hours) until Glacier Upload is completely done or can i close the application after getting the archive ID and upload will happen asynchronously. I have Similar doubt for glacier Download.

Thanks,
Haseena

Comment: What do you mean, "until upload is.completely done?"  How are you defining "done?"  Please clarify how your concept of "done" would be observable or quantifiable. I assume you do not mean when the actual data has been transferred from your computer, since it seems fairly obvious that it won't magically happen if you exit your application before you have finished sending bytes.  The download answer is simple, and I will answer that after I understand the upload portion of the question.

Comment: Actually i am running a backup service to upload file to glacier. now say depending on my frequency interval for example the backup starts at evening 5 pm and a person shutdown the system at 6 pm,  so how the backup will behave.Could you please help me with the working of glacier, i will really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You need to keep application running until glacier upload complete? You can also look for Uploading Large Archives in Parts option ([Multipart Upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/uploading-archive-mpu.html)).

Upload and download are different in Glacier.

Retrieving an archive from Amazon Glacier is a two-step process:

1. Initiate an archive retrieval job : It approximately takes 4-5 hours to complete. When you initiate a job, Amazon Glacier returns a job ID in the response and executes the job asynchronously. **So in this case you don't need to application running**.
2. You can also specify an Amazon Simple Notification Service (Amazon SNS) topic to which Amazon Glacier can post a notification after the job is completed. Amazon Glacier sends notification only after it completes the job.
3. After the job completes, you can download the job output.

[Disclousre : [Bucket Explorer](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/)]

Comment: thanks for the feedback, i tried downloading glacier archive using high level .net API but it dint work asynchronously. I called a download method in a thread and my thread was waiting for the download to complete. could you please suggest me on it, an example can actually help me out, from past 2 days i am struggling on it. i tried with Low level API's as well.